# Array formula not calculating on Excel MAC 2020

Tags: excel, macos

I have an issue with my Mac to enter an array formula.

I detail what I did so far.

1. I choose the output cells of the formula
2. Write the formula
3. press CMD+SHIFT+RETURN

It does not transform the formula into an array formula with the brackets {},

It only makes a line break on my formula. I tried pressing F2 upfront CMD+SHIFT+RETURN but it doesn't work neither.

Can you help me with this one ?

I've seen there are many people having the same issue on Excel Mac 2020, but didn't find any solution so far.

Best

Comment: I won't be able to test this for you, but isn't it just COMMAND+RETURN?

Comment: There is no version 2020 for Mac. I believe it's Ctrl+Shift+Enter on current versions that actually require array-entry.